# Too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I get the to many re-renders error

I tried to use useEffect to only render when weater changes

```
function DashboardHeaderContent({ looks, weather }) {
  const [seasonRange, setSeasonRange] = React.useState();

  function renderLook(look) {
    return <Look id={look._id} img={look.img} title={look.title} />;
  }

  if (weather.temp >= 7 && weather.temp <= 16) {
    setSeasonRange("Spring");
  } else if (weather.temp >= 16 && weather.temp <= 50) {
    setSeasonRange("Sommer");
  } else if (weather.temp >= 6 && weather.temp <= 18) {
    setSeasonRange("Fall");
  } else if (weather.temp <= 7) {
    setSeasonRange("Winter");
  }
```

The state should set depending on weather.temp

Comment: Why use state if you can already compute the value with `weather.temp`?

Comment: Also, your condition will return `"Fall"` only if `weather.temp === 6` specifically.

Comment: The reason for too many re-renders is because you're calling `setSeasonRange` each time the component renders, which triggers a new render.

Answer (score 4):

You could use useEffect() with an empty array as the second argument to prevent it observing any states. So it would essentially only run once.

```js
function DashboardHeaderContent({ looks, weather }) {
  const [seasonRange, setSeasonRange] = React.useState();

  function renderLook(look) {
    return <Look id={look._id} img={look.img} title={look.title} />;
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (weather.temp >= 7 && weather.temp <= 16) {
      setSeasonRange("Spring");
    } else if (weather.temp >= 16 && weather.temp <= 50) {
      setSeasonRange("Sommer");
    } else if (weather.temp >= 6 && weather.temp <= 18) {
      setSeasonRange("Fall");
    } else if (weather.temp <= 7) {
      setSeasonRange("Winter");
    }
  }, []);
```